Leslie Nielsen(?) and "molten steel"
Several years ago I was on a plane and they were playing a movie, and I don't remember very much of it now, but I remember a running gag that one of the characters--I think he was played by Leslie Nielsen--would repeatedly find ways to shoehorn the term "molten steel" into whatever he was talking about, using it to denote "something very good."
For example, "she was so excited, her eyes were shining like molten steel!"
I know that's really not much to go on, but can anyone identify this movie?

What does "several years ago" mean? Did it seem like the movie was a newer movie when you saw it (knowing most on airlines are only a few months old)? Anything else stand out about the movie? Knowing that Leslie Nielsen died in 2010 makes it harder for him to have been the star you are talking about.

@Paulster2: It was quite a while before he died.

So what does "several years ago" mean, then?

I'd think Spy Hard would be a good bet, given that it stars Leslie Nielsen as a spy named Dick Steele.  You'd expect thousands of steel-related puns, but oddly this transcript doesn't show any, and specifically no "molten steel".

I was looking for the same quote, and all I could find was your post! So I started going through all his movies on IMDB, when I came across this one:
 Rent-a-Kid (1995)
Then I remembered Leslie played the part of the owner of a rental company, and I knew it had to be it! So I got hold of a copy (YouTube) and lo and behold:
11:01, when talking about a piece of glassware: "...sterile as molten steel!"
17:11 "... it's gonna shoot to the top like molten steel!"
There may be more instances (I didn't watch the whole thing and Leslie's part is not all that big) but this is definitely the movie!

Yes, it definitely is.  Thanks!
